# communicating from another docker container in ECS cluster

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2, amazon-ecs

Let's take this part of docker-compose.yml

```
 eurekaserver:
   image:  XXXXX
   ports:
       - "8761:8761"
  zuulserver:
    image: XXXXX
    ports:
      - "5555:5555"
      - "5556:5556"
    environment:
      PROFILE: "default"
      SERVER_PORT: "5555"
      DEBUG_PORT: "5556"
      EUREKASERVER_URI: "http://eurekaserver:8761/eureka/"
      EUREKASERVER_PORT: "8761"
```

In my local machine I can communicate from zuulserver to eurekaserver. I checked it via `nc -z eurekaserver $EUREKASERVER_PORT`, but when I try to execute `nc -z eurekaserver $EUREKASERVER_PORT` from inside zuulserver container in ECS cluster after importing docker images via `ecs-cli compose --file docker-compose.yml up` I get

> nc: getaddrinfo: Name does not resolve